# Can I use pearl barley instead of rice in baked rice pudding?

Tags: baking, rice, barley

I want to make a baked rice pudding with plums. I was wondering since pearl barley is sometimes used for risotto if I could use it instead of rice here too. Will it bet the sticky, sort of slimy consistency rice gets when boiled in milk?

Comment: You might want to look up "frumenty", a medieval dish (sometimes) prepared similarly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else was wondering too, I tried it and it worked fine. It's not exactly the same consistency as when using rice but I still enjoyed it very much.

Comment: I'm not surprised, because I've had a pearl barley risotto (and it was delicious)